# Increase Hit detection on ItemizedOverlay

Tags: android, itemizedoverlay, overlayitem

I have an itemizedOverlay extended and I want to increase the hit detection on the OverLayItem's if this is possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was sorted by detecting the hit on the view below it and creating an invisible touch area.